# How to set state a variable from another file in react

Tags: reactjs, database, state

I have a state variable "day" in a "first file" declared like that :

```
const [day, setDay] = useState('');
```

trying to clean my code i have to move the code of "setDay" in another file that i call service where i want all the database stuff of my program.

my question is how to access to the setDay method from another file and be able to fill it with the result of my database.
thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a JS file: "service.js":

```
function change(val , setFunc){
   setFunc(val);
}
export default change;
```

then invoke the above "change" in your component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import change from "./service";

export default function App() {
   const [day, setDay] = useState("Monday");
   
   change("Sunday" , setDay);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called Lifting State Up its mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#:%7E:text=In%20React%2C%20sharing%20state%20is,it%20into%20the%20Calculator%20instead.) in react docs.

Comment: Here are the new docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `useState` should be only called in the component.

If you want to have a centralized state file, then look at React Context or a state library like MobX.

If you just want to split the `useState` part of a component (that is only used in that one component) into another file, look at creating a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create child component for changing day. This is where you will access `setDay` function that you pass from parent component

`ChangeDay.js`

```js
export const ChangeDay = ({ onHandleDay }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Button below to change:</h2>
      <button onClick={() => onHandleDay("TUESDAY")}>CLICK ME</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then inside `App.js` pass `setDay` to `onHandleDay` prop.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { ChangeDay } from "./ChangeDay";

export default function App() {
  const [day, setDay] = useState("Monday");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {day}</h1>
      <ChangeDay onHandleDay={setDay} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-flower-7negnk)